# jQuery notify plugin not working in another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery notify plugin. I include all the JS files in header. Now I am calling the `$.notify` function in another JS file where I am using AJAX, but there I cannot access the `$.notify` function.

My ajax file is here which I am including in header also:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'index.php?page=ajax_insertdimension.php',
    type:'post',
    data:'code='+dcode+'&des='+ddesc,
    success:function(msg){
       $.notify({
        title: 'Email Notification',
        text: 'You received an e-mail from your boss. You should read it right now!',
        image: "<img src='images/Mail.png'/>"
    }, {
        style: 'metro',
        className: 'info',
        autoHide: false,
        clickToHide: true
    });
      addcols();    
    }
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for success method to work, you have to specify what data type "msg" argument is there in parameter for success function. This can be done by adding `dataType` parameter to post method as specified in documentation here [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
url:'index.php?page=ajax_insertdimension.php',
type:'post',
data:'code='+dcode+'&des='+ddesc,
success:function(msg){
   $.notify({
    title: 'Email Notification',
    text: 'You received an e-mail from your boss. You should read it right now!',
    image: "<img src='images/Mail.png'/>"
}, {
    style: 'metro',
    className: 'info',
    autoHide: false,
    clickToHide: true
});
  addcols();    
},dataType: "json"})
```

This should do the work for you. You can put a debugger in success function and test, whether your callback is even getting called or not.

Comment: not its not working .. actually all my js files are included in header .. this like my notify.js and test1.js .. and i am using ajax in test1.js and calling notify.js function

Comment: did you made sure your success function is getting called or not, like putting a console log or debugger?

Comment: what is your response type? is it json or something else?, could you tell me what is the value of `msg`

Comment: its simple html not json